# Firebase has not been correctly initialized?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, android-studio

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

//void main() {
//  runApp(MyApp());
//}
void main() async {
  print('-- main');
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print('-- WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized');
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('-- main: Firebase.initializeApp');
  runApp(MyApp());}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Anket"),
        ),
        body: SurveyList(),
        ),
    );
  }
}

class SurveyList extends StatelessWidget {
  SurveyList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('dilanketi');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: users.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        }
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(document['isim']),
                  subtitle: Text(document['oy'].toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

here is pubscpec.yaml

```
dependencies:

  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10
  firebase_core: ^1.13.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.11
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

here is android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.anket_demo_app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        //minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

here is android/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.anket_demo_app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        //minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

end finally output error is

I/flutter ( 5874): -- main

I/flutter ( 5874): -- WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized

E/flutter ( 5874): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]

Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.

E/flutter ( 5874):

E/flutter ( 5874): Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.

E/flutter ( 5874):
E/flutter ( 5874): View the documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization

E/flutter ( 5874):
E/flutter ( 5874): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:99:9)

E/flutter ( 5874):

E/flutter ( 5874): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40:31)

E/flutter ( 5874):

E/flutter ( 5874): #2      main (package:anket_demo_app/main.dart:12:3)

E/flutter ( 5874): 
E/flutter ( 5874):

[image: i'd try almost everything pls help me]

also When 'new' in this code is deleted, it gives an error, and when it is not deleted, this figure gives an error

Comment: Based on the image provided it looks like that you haven't added yet the google-services file from firebase... Add it first then re run the app.

Comment: Worth to have a look, https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli